# UaException in userdatabase-example

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I'm trying to run the userdatabase standalone-example from the [eclipse milo project](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/tree/master/milo-examples/standalone-examples), however i am getting a UaException when i run the Client.jar. How can i fix this issue?

I followed the guide and build the Client and Server jar with Maven as described. The Server ran just fine, but as soon as i run the Client i am recieving the UaException.
There is no Users.db in the trusted Folder and the Users.db in the rejected Folder has no entries, so i can't Change anything there.

I was running it on Fedora 28, with Java Version 1.8 and Maven Version 3.5.2.

EDIT: I tried to include all logs, but it seems that was too much. If there is Need for more i can include all of it with pastebin.

Maven build (not sure if the Warning here might be the cause):

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.eclipse.milo:standalone-examples:jar:0.2.5-SNAPSHOT
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ org.eclipse.milo:standalone-examples:[unknown-version], /home/angelo/builds/milo/milo-examples/standalone-examples/pom.xml, line 167, column 21
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[[1;33mWARNING[m]
```

Log of Client.jar (Server throws the same Exception, and it only gets thrown after i run the Client, but i can include the Server Output as well if necessary):

```
11:52:00.979 [main] ERROR o.e.m.e.c.SecureClientStandaloneRunner - Error running client example: UaException: status=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, message=status=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, description=An error occurred verifying security.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaException: status=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, message=status=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, description=An error occurred verifying security.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at org.eclipse.milo.examples.client.ClientWithUserNameAndPasswordExample.run(ClientWithUserNameAndPasswordExample.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.milo.examples.client.SecureClientStandaloneRunner.run(SecureClientStandaloneRunner.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.milo.examples.client.ClientWithUserNameAndPasswordExample.main(ClientWithUserNameAndPasswordExample.java:40)
Caused by: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaException: status=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, description=An error occurred verifying security.
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.handlers.UaTcpClientMessageHandler.onError(UaTcpClientMessageHandler.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.handlers.UaTcpClientMessageHandler.decodeMessage(UaTcpClientMessageHandler.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.handlers.UaTcpClientMessageHandler.decode(UaTcpClientMessageHandler.java:392)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec$1.decode(ByteToMessageCodec.java:42)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:491)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:430)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec.channelRead(ByteToMessageCodec.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1304)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:921)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:135)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors mean you probably didn't follow the instructions for generating a key store and/or accepting the certificates.

It may be easier to start with the other examples in the `milo-examples` module. This one is somewhat unmaintained and has been removed from the next release.